# SQL for Inserting the system date and a fixed time (not the system time) in a column

Tags: oracle, toad

I have a query like this:

```
Insert into UNITRIP (START_TIME, END_TIME)
   (TO_DATE('10/20/2015 06:05:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('10/20/2015 07:34:06', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

I require a sql where the start_time is of this type: system-date 06:05:00 (fixed date is to be replaced by `sysdate`).

How to write a query for this?

Answer (score 3):

If you're asking for an expression that returns 6:05am on the current day

```
trunc(sysdate) + interval '6:05' hour to minute
```

Comment: Justin, I want to write an insert SQL that is a replacement for the query i wrote. Except that the date portion is replaced by system date

Comment: @LoneWolf91 - It sounds like you just want to replace the `to_date` expressions with the expression I posted (you'd obviously need to adjust the interval to produce a different time).  If that is not actually what you want, I'm afraid that you'll probably need to clarify your question.

Comment: Okay, this works. I specifically required this: trunc(sysdate) + interval '6:05:00' hour to seconds. 
Thanks Justin